# Algorithm for multicriterial arrangement

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matching

Let me describe problem in a form of a small fiction story.

### The story

In a Brave New World new cities are built in a couple of days and only need to be populated. Moreover, there's no more long boring hiring process, no interviews and subjective decisions - every person passes several tests and their results are used to find best employees.

When new city is built, number of companies place their offices there and ask Super Mind to *find best employees* for them given a way to calculate person's **score** for their **particular company**. People on their side ask Super Mind to find work for them. They give him **list of companies** where they would like to work together with corresponding **priorities**. Super Mind is very humanistic, so its task is to find such **arrangement** that **people get to the best companies they want**, even if some companies will left without employees at all.

### Formal definition

Now let me define the task more formally.

- `E` - number of employees seeking for a job.
- `C` - number of companies.
- `S(e,c)` - score of employee `e` for company `c`.
- `Pr(e,c)` - priority of company `c` in a personal "wishlist" of employee `e`.
- `P(c)` - # of positions available in company `c`.

**Task**: obtain list of `(e, c)` tuples given following conditions:

- employees with higher `S(e,c)` should always go first (e.g. if there's only one position left in company `c` and there are 2 candidates for it, it should be guaranteed that employee with higher score gets to this position).
- employees should get to the company with highest priority available for them.

### My algorithm

The only algorithm I can think of that guarantees all conditions is as follows. First I create list of all possible applications from employees to companies (`A(e,c,s,p)`), where `s` is a score of employee `e` for company `c` and `p` is company priority for this employee. Then I sort all applications by total score and run next recursive procedure:

```
def arrange(As, Ps, not_approved, approved): 
    # As - list of applications left
    # Ps - map of type (company -> # of positions left)
    # not_approved - set of not approved applications
    # approved - set of approved applications (hold intermediate result)
    if (empty(As))
        return approved
    a = head(As)     
    As_rest = tail(As)  
    if (cant_be_hired(a))          # if no places left in company from this application
        return arrange(As_rest, Ps, not_approved + a, approved) 
    else if (highest_priority(a))  # if this application has highest of left priorities
        return arrange(As_rest, Ps(c) - 1, not_approved, approved + a)
    else 
        # if application can be accepted, but it has higher priorities left,  
        # check what will happen if we do not accept this application
        check_result = arrange(As_left, Ps, not_approved + a, approved)
        if (employee_is_hired_for_better_job(a, check_result))
           # if employee can be hired to a job with higher priority, 
           # just return check_result - it is already an answer
           return check_result
        else
           # otherwise accept this application and proceed for rest of them
           return arrange(As_rest, Ps, not_approved, approved + a)
```

But, of course, this algorithm has very large computational complexity. Dynamic programming with caching check results helps a bit, but this is still too slow.

I was thinking of some kind of conditional optimization algorithm that always converges, however I'm not so closely familiar with this field to find appropriate one.

So, **is there better algorithm**?

Comment: You may be interested in the [stable marriage problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

Comment: @n.m.: more specifically, this problem is very close to a problem from  National Resident Matching Program that has excellent [solution](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program#Matching_Algorithm). Thanks for the help! Feel free to post it as an answer so I could accept it and make question for helpful for others.